# shared memory in cuda

Tags: c, memory, cuda

I have a matrix, u, of size NxN of complex data, and I'd like to multiply elementwise each row by a vector, k, of size 1xN.  The data in u is stored row-wise.

I have two implementations of this.  One which takes advantage of shared memory, dividing the matrix into tiles, and another which does not.

I am finding that the shared memory implementation, multiply1, is not faster, and is systematically just as fast, or even slower than multiply2.

The shared memory implementation is as follows,

```
__global__ void multiply1(cufftComplex *u, cufftComplex *k) {
     __shared__ cufftComplex k_s[BLOCK_WIDTH];
     int idx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
     int idy = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
     int index;

     if (threadIdx.y == 0 && idx < N) {
         k_s[threadIdx.x] = k[idx];
     }
     __syncthreads();

     if (idx < N && idy < N) {
         index = N*idy + idx;
         u[index] = cuCmulf(k_s[threadIdx.x],u[index]);
     }

}
```

Whereas the global memory implementation is as follows,

```
__global__ void multiply2(cufftComplex *u, cufftComplex *k) {
        int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (idx < N*N) { 
            u[idx] =cuCmulf(k[idx % N],u[idx]);
        }
    }
```

and the main function call, for a matrix of size 64x64

```
dim3 block(16,16);
dim3 grid(4,4);
multiply1<<<grid, block>>>(d_u, d_k);
multiply2<<<16, 256>>>(d_u, d_k);
```

How can I use the profiler to find out why exactly multiply1 is not getting even a least a slight increase in speed?  Which metrics would elucidate what exactly is going on?

The profiler is telling me that for multiply1, I am getting 152 GB/s global memory load throughput, whereas for multiply2 I am getting 81 GB/s.  This is logical, because I'm loading less from global memory.  Shouldn't this translate into quicker execution?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been faster if you use it many times but here you are only using it one time. You transformed your problem in:

```
copy from global memory to shared memory
read from shared memory
```

instead of:

```
read from global memory
```

So yes it is certainly slower than the previous algorithm which use only the global memory. If you want to take advantage of shared memory, your algorithm as to read many times in it ifnot you won't overhead the global memory.

Comment: I copy from global memory the appropriate elements of k once per block, instead of once per element because of the if statement:
     if (threadIdx.y == 0 && idx < N)

There are overall less global memory loads.  Most of the global memory loads in multiply2 are replaced by shared memory loads, which have less latency...right?

Comment: Once per block but your threads in the same block is waiting for the copy to finish.

Comment: how would I check this?
would there be a way to do this in the profiler?

Comment: __syncthreads(); means wait for the above code to make sure all threads in the block have the same data. No need to use the profiler for that. The profiler give you useful information to optimize the usage of the registers and memory transfer from host to device and vice verse.